# Python HTML parsing script that takes array of URLs and outputs specific data about each of the URLs

Tags: python, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to write an HTML parser in Python that takes as its input a URL or list of URLs and outputs specific data about each of those URLs in the format:

URL: data1: data2

The data points can be found at the exact same HTML node in each of the URLs. They are consistently between the same starting tags and ending tags. If anyone out there would like to help an amateur python programmer get the job done, it would be greatly appreciated. Extra points if you can come up with a way to output the information that can be easily copied and pasted into an excel document for subsequent data analysis!

For example, lets say I would like to output the view count for a particular YouTube video. For the URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOdW1OuZ1U0, the view count is around 3.6 million. For all YouTube videos, this number is found in the following format within the page's source:

```
<span class="watch-view-count ">
    3,595,057
</span>
```

Fortunately, these exact tags are found only once on a particular YouTube video's page. These starting and ending tags can be inputted into the program or built-in and modified when necessary. The output of the program would be:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOdW1OuZ1U0: 3,595,057 (or 3595057).

Comment: Please post some samples and the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOdW1OuZ1U0'
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
span = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'watch-view-count'})
print '{}:{}'.format(url, span.text)
```

If you do not want to use `BeautifulSoup`, you can use `re`:

```
import urllib2
import re

url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOdW1OuZ1U0'
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()

pattern = re.compile('<span class="watch-view-count.*?([\d,]+).*?</span>', re.DOTALL)
r = pattern.search(data)
print '{}:{}'.format(url, r.group(1))
```

As for the outputs, I think you can store them in a csv file.

Comment: Does this require me to download the BeautifulSoup module?

Comment: Yes, I'm editing my answer to use `re`. No downloading is required.@jakelaz

Comment: can you please rewrite the original full code so that it contains Re implementations, not beautifulsoup?

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/employee folders/Interns/Summer 2013/Jacob Lazarus/testParser.py", line 9, in <module>
    print '{}:{}'.format(url, r.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Could you please post the source code the html file for me? Just a snippet around the `<span>`. In china, I can not visit youtube. So there is something wrong with the regex.@jakelaz

Comment: </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  </div>

</span></span><div id="watch7-views-info">      <span class="watch-view-count " >
    3,597,664
  </span>

    <div class="video-extras-sparkbars">
    <div class="video-extras-sparkbar-likes" style="width: 98.0295054717%"></div>
    <div class="video-extras-sparkbar-dislikes" style="width: 1.97049452833%"></div>
  </div>

Comment: It's OK now! There is one more space than I think and should use `search` not `match`. @jakelaz

Comment: It works! you've been an amazing help. One last question - how can I make it so that I can input an array or list of URLs and output an array or list of URL:data objects?

Comment: And also, I was hoping you could help me figure out my exact problem - would like to count the score of a reddit thread. Do you have access to reddit in China?

Comment: If you want input manually, use `input()`. Use a loop, get the input, and append it to a list. Then make the above code a function. Perform it on each url. It is a simple job, you can do it I think. And I'm glad your question is solved, but please accept my answer, give it a tick. :)@jakelaz

Comment: @zhanyangyu - is there any chance you could help me modify this program to find the following information within a reddit thread's source code? check out the source code here:

Comment: <time datetime="2013-07-10T18:49:23+00:00">10 Jul 2013</time></div><div class="score"><span class='number'>0</span>&#32;<span class='word'>points</span>&#32;(50% like it)</div>

Comment: I am looking to output the number 0, which is after <div class = "score"><span class = 'number'> AND before </span>. Note that <span class = 'number'> occurs over 5 times in the page's source, so selecting for the <div class = "score"> is necessary (I think)

Comment: This must be the last question for it 3 am now in China. And you'd better learn some regex, it must be easy for you. `patter = re.compile('''<div class="score"><span class='number'>(\d+)</span>''') pattern.search(data)`.@jakelaz

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `HTMLParser` over `re` for this type of task.  However, `HTMLParser` can be a bit tricky.  I use immutable objects to store data... I'm sure this this the wrong way of doing it.  But its worked with several projects for me in the past.

```
import urllib2
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import csv 

position = []
results = [""]

class hp(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'span' and ('class', 'watch-view-count ') in attrs:   
            position.append('bingo')

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'span' and 'bingo' in position:
            position.remove('bingo')

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if 'bingo' in position:
            results[0] += " " + data.strip() + " "


my_pages = ["http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOdW1OuZ1U0"]
data = []
for url in my_pages:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    page = str(response.read())
    parser = hp()
    parser.feed(page)
    data.append(results[0])

    # reinitialize immutiable objects
    position = []
    results = [""]

index = 0
with open('/path/to/test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = ['url', 'output']
    writer.writerow(header)
    for d in data:
        row = [my_pages[index], data[index]]
        writer.writerow(row)
        index += 1
```

Then just open /path/to/test.csv in Excel